# Streamlit error "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dados' referenced before assignment"

Tags: python, pandas, streamlit

I'm trying to plot some stock data using streamlit. I have a selectbox with two options: Home, Charts.

Home is the default page and is responsible to collect data from user, data as stock tickers, begin date and end date.

Charts is responsible to plot a line chart with those data.

My problem is in the Charts screen, because I can't read data altought I can read it in the Home page.

The error message is:

`UnboundLocalError: local variable 'dados' referenced before assignment`

My code is below:

```
# Importando o framework
import streamlit as st

# Libs de coleta, processamento e manipulação de dados
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import yfinance as yf
yf.pdr_override()
import pandas_datareader.data as web

# Libs de visualização de gráficos
import matplotlib.pyplot as plts

# TODO: conhecer mais sobre esta biblioteca. Referências: https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html,
# TODO: https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/api.html
#from bokeh.plotting import figure


# Título da página
st.title('Minerathon')

"""
    - Home: página inicial, aqui que o usuário insere os tickers e a data de início e fim.
    - Charts: página que retorna o gráfico das ações informadas na página Home.
"""
menu = ['Home', 'Charts']
# Utilizando um selectbox para identificar o que o usuário quer ver.
# choice - str
choice = st.sidebar.selectbox("Menu", menu)

"""
    - carteira: DataFrame inicialmente vazio, mas que depois guardará os Adj Close dos tickers que usuário inserir
    - ativos: lista inicialmente vazia, que armazenará o ticker (nome da ação + .SA) e que será iterada para compor a 
              carteira.
"""
carteira = pd.DataFrame()
ativos = []

"""
    - df: DataFrame
    - tickers: é uma lista que deve ser populada com os tickers
    - start: data de início, i.e, a partir de quando desejo analisar?!
    - end: data de fim, i.e, qual o útlimo dia que quero analisar?!
"""
def baixa_dados(df, tickers, start, end):
    for t in tickers:
        # web.get_data_yahoo - API que nos permite consultar os tickers e baixar os dados
        df[t] = web.get_data_yahoo(t, start=start, end=end)['Adj Close']
    return df


def main():
    if choice == 'Home':
        with st.form(key='main_form'):

            start = st.date_input('Data de início AAAA-MM-DD')
            end = st.date_input('Data de fim AAAA-MM-DD')

            for i in range(2):
                ativos.append(st.text_input('Cód. do ativo + .SA: ', key=str(i)))

            submit = st.form_submit_button(label='Enviar')
        # Baixando os dados do Yahoo
        if submit:
            dados = baixa_dados(df=carteira, tickers=ativos, start=start, end=end)
            st.line_chart(dados.head())

        # TODO: Redirecionar esse st.write(carteira) pra outra tela do menu intitulada 'Charts'.
        #st.line_chart(dados)

    if choice == 'Charts':
        """
            O problema está aqui.
            
            Eu gostaria de retornar um gráfico de linhas dos tickers recebidos na opção Home, mas não consigo.

        """
        st.line_chart(dados)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: The traceback helps locate the failing line. Consider the line `if submit:`. Suppose there is no submit and so `dados` is not set. You try to use it anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dados` variable is defined inside `choice == 'Home'` block.
So when you trying to use it inside `choice == 'Charts':` block with

```
st.line_chart(dados)
```

code line it is not defined there.
In order to use it in both blocks you should define it as a global variable / in scope containing both these methods.

Comment: I literally used dados outside choice == 'Home' but I got the follow error: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'submit' referenced before assignment`. Also I tried a few things with submit button, but nothing worked.

Comment: You are trying to USE it there, but it should be defined / initialized BEFORE that.

Comment: I solved using `st.session_state.dados` insteado of `dados = baixa_dados(...)`.

Thank you for the help!